# Merging [transparency] and [opacity] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The Main site currently has [12 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opacity+transparency) tagged using [transparency](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency) AND [opacity](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opacity).

Do we need both tags?

I ask because 100% transparency is the same as 0% opacity, and vice versa.

Our wikis for the two tags reinforce their inter-dependence:

- [transparency](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency):

> The ability to make a GIS layer transparent. That is, the ability to
> adjust the opacity or transparency of a layer to allow information
> below the layer to be visible.

- [opacity](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opacity):

> The condition of lacking transparency or translucence; opaqueness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose that we merge the two tags into a single new tag named [transparency-opacity](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transparency-opacity) with the two original tags being kept as synonyms of it.